# Generate a list of json objects after encoding

Tags: flutter, dart

`var encoded_tags = json.encode(tag);`

gives me a list like this:

```
{"id":"0","name":"Peter"}
{"id":"1","name":"Max"}
""
```

My question is how can I have `[Peter,Max]` list from this data?
**NOTE** The third item is empty.
My tag Model is:

```
class Tag {
  int id = 0;
  String name = '';

  Tag(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;

  }

  Tag.fromJson(Map json)
      : id = json['id'],
        name = json['name'];

  Map toJson() {
    return {'id': id, 'name': name};
  }
}
```

I tried `encoded_tags['name']` but it doesn't work.

PS: Here is the complete code:
tag value is coming from an API get request, it has a Map type

```
class tagRetrievePreview extends StatelessWidget {
  var tag;
 
  tagRetrievePreview(this.tag, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Card(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 224, 223, 223),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            side: const BorderSide(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 83, 83, 83),
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text( 
                      tag.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print('Delete tag button tapped');
                    },
                    child: const CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 8,
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 117, 112, 112),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.close,
                          size: 13,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                        )),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And the output is the list of 3 elements that I mentioned above,
I just want it to be a list of the name values.
Inspecting tag value result:
[image]

Comment: Could you please post your full code?How encode provides empty string?
json.encode will provide you a json string. How can you use encoded_tags['name'] and get values? Only if you decode you can access like that.

Comment: @GowthamKK the tag value is coming from an API get request, and it is the input for `TagRetrievePreview`. I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

The variable `tag` itself has the name and id. If you do json encode you are converting it to a string from which you cant access items like how you access from a key value pair.

You can access name and id like

```dart
//var encoded_tags = json.encode(tag);
// Remove the line above
print(tag.name);
print(tag.id);
```

**EDIT**

Use this model for Tag

```
class Tag {
  String? name;
  String? id;

  Tag({this.name, this.id});

  Tag.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    id = json['id'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Then to convert your response to this type use

```
List<Tag> _tag = json.decode(response.body).map((item)=> Tag.fromJson(item));
print(_tag[0].id);
print(_tag[0].name);
```

Comment: I attached the complete code, `tag.id` doesn't work

Comment: Edited my answer.. The response shows that Id is string but in your model you have the ID has int.

Comment: no it's an integer

Comment: In the sample response that you have provided its written inside double quotes.

Comment: If its int change the type in model to int? for the id

Comment: both int and int? are ok, my question is about parsing the data

Comment: Its written in the answer at last.. Tag.fromJson(json.decode(response.body.toString()); this should parse it properly and you should be able to get the id and name from the variable

Comment: Edited it for converting a list of names

Comment: `FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)`

Comment: not sure maybe that's because of the empty string that's at the last